# Does the Grothendieck group of a triangulated category functor has an adjoint?

Tags: abelian-groups, triangulated-categories

I know $K_0:\textbf{CMon}\to\textbf{Ab}$ is left adjoint to the forgetful functor, associating to an abelian group its structure of commutative monoid.

It's also true that we can somehow generalize the Grothendieck group functor to the category $\textbf{TrCat}$ of (essentially) small triangulated categories and triangulated functors between them. It associates to a triangulated category the free abelian group on objects modulo relations imposed by distinguished triangles. Does it have an adjoint functor in this case? Or maybe is there a way to canonically consider a triangulated category starting from an abelian group?